# How to make my app visible in Safari share options

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, sharing

Is there a way to register my app so that it is visible as one of the available share options in mobile Safari?

I want my app to show up on this list, the way the Pocket app does, so I can enable it and have it be listed in the share options along with Facebook, Twitter, Pocket as shown in the second image.
[image: I want my image to show up]
[image: Tapping on share]

I've also tried following the instructions at this link, but it doesn't seem to work

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1587/_index.html

Comment: See the [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214). This would appear to be a "share" extension.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy that was it. If you want you can add that an answer and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rmaddy mentioned, this can be done by following the instructions on [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214)

In reference to photo I posted, a share extension would show up on the top row, and an action extension would show up on the bottom (black and white) row.